# CSS files fails to load on first request of Nodejs/Express web app. Works fine from second request onwards

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have created a basic web app that displays some items after reading them from a json file.

So, there's a form, and on adding input and submitting that form, the input gets written in the json file. After that, it is redirected to a page where I display the json file.

When I add some input in the form and submit it, it gets redirected to the page where I show the data from the json file. But the css files fails to load and I am left with a html page with no styling.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJbG.png)

But on reloading this page, the css files loads and I have styling.

[See this image, CSS files have been loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI1gv.png)

Here is my .ejs code which gets loaded as html in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>
        <%= title%>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/product.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="main-header">
        <nav class="main-header__nav">
            <ul class="main-header__item-list">
                <li class="main-header__item"><a class="active" href="/">Shop</a></li>
                <li class="main-header__item"><a href="/admin/add-product">Add Product</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <% if(prods.length> 0) { %>
            <div class="grid">
                <% for(let product of prods) { %>
                    <article class="card product-item">
                        <header class="card__header">
                            <h1 class="product__title">
                                <%= product.title%>
                            </h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="card__image">
                            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/31/20/51/book-1296045_960_720.png"
                            alt="A Book">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__content">
                            <h2 class="product__price">$19.99</h2>
                            <p class="product__description">A very interesting book about so many even more interesting
                            things!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__actions">
                            <button class="btn">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <% } %>
            </div>
            <% } else { %>
                <h1>No products found!</h1>
            <% } %>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the where I render the .ejs file.

```
exports.showProducts = (req, res, next) => {
Product.fetchAll(products => {
    res.render('shop.ejs', {
        prods: products,
        title: 'My Shop',
        path: '/',
        hasProducts: products.length > 0,
        activeShop: true,
        productCSS: true
    });
    // console.log(adminData.products);
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'shop.html'));

});
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not not post screen shots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Add your code to this question.

Comment: @disinfor Okay. I have edited my question.

Comment: There are quite a few things that can cause a [status of "failed" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Chrome+status+failed). More information might be needed.